# How to set output video file size in Handbrake 1.1.1?

Tags: handbrake

There used to be an option in older versions of [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) to set a target file size for the video file it outputs. However, it seems that option is no longer there in the UI.

Does anybody have any solution for that? Probably using the "Extra Options" box at the video tab?
[image]

Answer (score 12):

[Vidcoder](http://vidcoder.net/) is a Windows-only alternative front end for Handbrake and offers the target size option.  You don't need to install Handbrake separately.

Here's the target size option:
[image: Vidcoder Size Option]

Answer (score 10):

HandBrake 0.9.5 (released January 4, 2011) was the last version to support the "target size" feature. You can download an old version of HandBrake from their [Old Releases page](https://handbrake.fr/old.php).

Or you can compute the final file size using the following formula

```
File size (kb) = bitrate(kbps) x running time (s)
```

If you want it in MB, then divide the result by 1000.

Comment: Using this formula and dividing by 1000 will only get you a size in megabits so not the usual MB (bytes) all our disk sizes display. You have to then divide by 8 to have a number of bytes.

Comment: Also do not forget to add the audio bitrate of the audio track(s).

Answer (score 3):

The devs have [stated publicly](https://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=38466) that they will not be bringing this feature back (disappointing imo, since there are many valid use cases for it).

One workaround: download [this handy calculator app from Christian Wheel](https://www.christianwheel.com/post/2017/01/23/bitrate-calculator), which will give you a value to put in the "Avg Bitrate" field to achieve a certain output size.

Answer (score 0):

filesize (kb) = bitrate (kbps/8) x seconds

byte = 8 bits

And to be precise, if you want it in MB just divide the result value by 1024 or 1048576 for Gb example: constant bitrate: 2750/8*7200 sec /1024/1024 = 2.36GB slightly larger for audio track(s)

Now, if you don't need to be that precise, and a movie is around 2 hours:

2750 kbps will give you around 2.75 GB

3500 kbps will give you around 3.5 GB

4000 kbps will give you around 4 GB

and so on

Answer (score -1):

If you want to target MegaBytes, and are using 1024 Bytes = 1 MegaByte, then use this formula:

File size in MegaBytes = ( bitrate in kbps x running time in sec ) / 1024

Hence, if you want to target a size in MegaBytes, using basic algebra we can manipulate the function to get your average bitrate using this formula. Then just plug the calculated bitrate in the Avg Bitrate section of the Video tab in Handbrake:

Bitrate in kbps = ( File size in MegaBytes * 1024 ) / (Running time in sec)